# Redirected by django updateview but not updated

Tags: django

I created an update screen for django. However, although it redirects to successURL, the data has not been updated. I don't know why.

I need your help.
I will post it if necessary.

```
#view
class RecordDetailEdit(UpdateView,LoginRequiredMixin):
  template_name = 'records/detail_edit.html'
  model = URC
  form_class = RecordDetailEditForm
  pk_url_kwarg = 'id'
  success_url = reverse_lazy('person:home')

  def get_object(self):
    return get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.request.user.user_id)

  def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(RecordDetailEdit, self).get_form_kwargs()
    # get users, note: you can access request using: self.request
    kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
    return kwargs
```

```
#form
class RecordDetailEditForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = URC
    fields = ('UPRC','URN','UET','URT')

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user')
    super(RecordDetailEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['URN'].queryset = UPRM.objects.filter(user=user)
```

```
#model
class URC(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    UPRC = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    URN = models.ForeignKey(UPRM, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    UET = models.DurationField(editable=True)
    URT = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.UPRC
```

```
#url
path('<id>/edit/', views.RecordDetailEdit.as_view(), name='record_detail_edit'),
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to the following.
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
      obj = URC.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id'])
      return obj